# clipboardData - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript

This is the code that throws the error, not sure why, it used to work with Chrome. I'm using Chromium now and its throwing the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

```
$wnd.addEventListener("paste",processEvent);
        function processEvent(e) {
    if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {
        console.log("clipboard from event"); // can see in console log
        var items = e.clipboardData.items;
        if(items.length == 0){ // error here

        }
    }
}
```

So it seems that the problem is `var items` is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check if the `items` is defined first

> $wnd.addEventListener("paste",processEvent);

```
    function processEvent(e) {

if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {

    console.log("clipboard from event"); // can see in console log
    var items = e.clipboardData.items;
    if(items != undefined && items.length == 0){ // error here

    }
}
}
```

But you [cannot read or set clip board data in JavaScript](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Granting_JavaScript_access_to_the_clipboard)

Comment: Right, this will check if items is null but I guess it still wont solve the issue why its null

Comment: Right, I updated your question, why do you think you can read the clipboard data

Comment: I don't entirely agree with this, with Google Chrome (in Windows) I have made it work before, with the same code I have, I'm just not sure why in Linux its not the same

Comment: hm..I would like to play with this too, why dont you create a sjfiddle where i can just grab the code and paste it in my IDE. I am on ubuntu